# Mailto link in MS Adaptive Card Action (Teams) opens new email window twice

Tags: microsoft-teams, mailto, adaptive-cards

I have set up an incoming webhook in MS Teams that includes an action to answer to the question posted via email. The answer email contains the question quoted with '>' at the beginning of each line.

The problem is that the email composer window opens twice as if I would click the button in Teams two times.

See the example code below.

```json
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application\/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl": null,
            "content": {
                "$schema": "http:\/\/adaptivecards.io\/schemas\/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.2",
                "msteams": {
                    "width": "Full"
                },
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "wrap": "true",
                        "text": "This is a bit longer message. This is a bit longer message. This is a bit longer message. This is a bit longer message. This is a bit longer message. This is a bit longer message. \r\nIt contains a line break.\r\n\r\nThere are also empty lines.\r\n\r\nSee you. test@test.com. Testing some glyphs: - \u00d6\u00f5."
                    }],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "url": "mailto:name-email@test.com?subject=VS%3A%20Message&body=Hi%21%0d%0aThank%20you%21%0d%0a%0a%0aSender%A4%3A%20name%2Demail%40test.com%0D%0AAbout%3A%20Test%0D%0AWe%3A%20testing%20%28this%40test.com%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%0D%0A%3E%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%0D%0A%3E%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%20This%20is%20a%20bit%20longer%20message.%0D%0A%3E%20%0D%0A%3E%20It%20contains%20a%20line%20break.%0D%0A%3E%20%0D%0A%3E%20There%20are%20also%20empty%0D%0A%3E%20lines.%0D%0A%3E%20%0D%0A%3E%20See%20you.%20test%40test.com.%20Testing%20some%20glyphs%3A%20%2D%0D%0A%3E%20%C3%96%C3%B5.",
                        "title": "Send"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When e.g. copying the mailto part into MS Word as a hyperlink and clicking it, the email composer window opens just one time. When clicking the button in the Adaptive card, it opens twice.

I could test this only with MS Outlook 365.

Can somebody spot where the culprit is?

Comment: We tried sending the above scenario and it is opening email composer only once. We have sent the adaptive card through incoming webhook and Bot as well - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcKNV.png. 
Only difference is we have shortened the url to - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BoJ5.png. Could you please let me know if you are doing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: This is a common issue with Adaptive cards. We faced a similar issue where we were capturing user responses in the bot. Their support couldn't resolve it as well. We had to fix it programmatically. There is a unique `id` attached to each adaptive card. You can use it and prevent the repeating action.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. Obviously the bug doesn't appear in all installations; we have had it since about two or three weeks and I thought it would be caused by a modification I did to the adaptive card's mailto link. If it is not related to that issue than the bug might disappear at some point whith both Teams and Outlook updating.